# Wix Toolset: Running "Remove" from msi file does not work

Tags: wix, wix3.9

I have a Wix Toolset project that uses **WixUI_Minimal**.

When I install from the generated MSI file, the app installs normally.

When I click on the MSI file again, I have two options: **Repair** & **Remove**.

Clicking on **Remove** attempts to un-install the app, but it fails, rolls back and tell me that the setup wizard has ended prematurely.

If I uninstall the application from **"Add/Remove Programs"** it works fine and the application is removed.

what can be wrong here?

### UPDATE

This is part of the log file when attempting to remove the app from the MSI:

```
MSI (s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:054]: Executing op:
RegAddValue(Name=UninstallString,Value=#%MsiExec.exe
/X{C23520BB-5E8C-4B0A-AC6A-E3795798123F},) MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:054]: Executing op: RegCreateKey() MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:054]: Executing op:
RegAddValue(Name=EstimatedSize,Value=#236,) MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:054]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Size,,) MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:054]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Readme,,) MSI (s)
(D8:94) [16:26:52:055]: Executing op:
RegAddValue(Name=Publisher,Value=Mina Samy,) MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:055]: Executing op: RegCreateKey() MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:055]: Executing op: RegCreateKey() MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:055]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=NoModify,Value=#1,) MSI
(s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:055]: Executing op:
RegAddValue(Name=ModifyPath,Value=#%MsiExec.exe
/X{C23520BB-5E8C-4B0A-AC6A-E3795798123F},) MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:056]: Executing op:
RegAddValue(Name=LocalPackage,Value=C:\Windows\Installer\1ac64ab4.msi,)
MSI (s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:056]: Executing op: RegCreateKey() MSI (s)
(D8:94) [16:26:52:056]: Executing op:
RegAddValue(Name=InstallSource,Value=D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Wix\MyMetroApp\MyWixProject\bin\Debug\,)
MSI (s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:056]: Executing op:
RegAddValue(Name=InstallLocation,,) MSI (s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:056]:
Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=InstallDate,Value=20150224,) MSI (s)
(D8:94) [16:26:52:057]: Executing op:
RegAddValue(Name=HelpTelephone,,) MSI (s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:057]:
Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=HelpLink,,) MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:057]: Executing op:
RegAddValue(Name=DisplayVersion,Value=1.0.0.0,) MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:057]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Contact,,) MSI (s)
(D8:94) [16:26:52:058]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=Comments,,) MSI
(s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:058]: Executing op:
RegAddValue(Name=AuthorizedCDFPrefix,,) MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:058]: Executing op:
RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483646,Key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\TempPackages,,BinaryType=1,,)
MSI (s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:058]: Executing op:
RegRemoveValue(Name=C:\Windows\Installer\1ac64ab4.msi,Value=#0,) MSI
(s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:058]: Executing op: RegRemoveKey() MSI (s)
(D8:94) [16:26:52:058]: Note: 1: 1402 2:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\TempPackages
3: 2  MSI (s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:059]: Executing op:
RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483646,Key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\BB02532CC8E5A0B4CAA63E97758921F3\Transforms,,BinaryType=1,,)
MSI (s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:059]: Executing op: RegRemoveKey() MSI (s)
(D8:94) [16:26:52:059]: Note: 1: 1402 2:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\BB02532CC8E5A0B4CAA63E97758921F3\Transforms
3: 2  MSI (s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:059]: Executing op:
End(Checksum=0,ProgressTotalHDWord=0,ProgressTotalLDWord=0) MSI (s)
(D8:94) [16:26:52:059]: Error in rollback skipped.  Return: 5 MSI (s)
(D8:94) [16:26:52:062]: Note: 1: 2318 2:   MSI (s) (D8:94)
[16:26:52:064]: No System Restore sequence number for this
installation. MSI (s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:064]: Unlocking Server MSI (s)
(D8:94) [16:26:52:077]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting UpdateStarted
property. Its current value is '1'. Action ended 16:26:52: INSTALL.
Return value 3. Property(S): UpgradeCode =
{E37719C6-EE47-415C-9789-F36457739F83} Property(S):
dirACF43D92150056BB5AF1BB3AF4AA9367 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\ Property(S):
dir85CD6D2E073C1AF7CCDD7F08B2828B13 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\
Property(S): dir27E2307338ED99741CE34470D7788F0A = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\cs-CZ\
Property(S): dir1737C711EC8ED7C44C1E30F357D02AC9 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\de-DE\
Property(S): dirB7BDE730B1FC6C8BAAEE9AE582B59FE7 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\en-US\
Property(S): dirDBCF52942BF84D8199FD0C3E2DE9ABA9 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\es-ES\
Property(S): dir74E6C4D40426FE7774C8697FFE6F97E4 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\fr-FR\
Property(S): dirEFF012DC0AAE03E3EAAA4821310C9DA4 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\it-IT\
Property(S): dir3C1D2B6785564FAB46D3040FC9CE4264 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\ja-JP\
Property(S): dir6A4E8B36315C88E1798B918ACF2988FD = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\ko-KR\
Property(S): dir3AD1E29BAEB95A64A569093166405201 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\pl-PL\
Property(S): dir9E520796F0CE303B4506F5EF7767C416 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\pt-BR\
Property(S): dirC238DC7D4277CB05BF94AF487B5D5D1E = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\ru-RU\
Property(S): dir53726EBC16CC1C77755E74D187F9A1AE = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\tr-TR\
Property(S): dirF3AB69CAA487FCD07F63CA17BEA4EB9E = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\zh-CN\
Property(S): dir9D7E2D39FDCE546D1355C94BD1276EF9 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\zh-TW\
Property(S): INSTALLFOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\MyWixProject\
Property(S): WixUIRMOption = UseRM Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): ARPNOMODIFY = 1 Property(S):
CustomAction.RemoveAppPackage = "" -NoProfile -NonInteractive
-InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyWixProject\Remove-AppPackage.ps1" "com.minasamy.MyMetroApp"
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\ Property(S):
TARGETDIR = D:\ Property(S): Installed = 00:00:00 Property(S):
Manufacturer = Mina Samy Property(S): ProductCode =
{C23520BB-5E8C-4B0A-AC6A-E3795798123F} Property(S): ProductLanguage =
1033 Property(S): ProductName = MyWixProject Property(S):
ProductVersion = 1.0.0.0 Property(S): DefaultUIFont =
WixUI_Font_Normal Property(S): WixUI_Mode = Minimal Property(S):
ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg Property(S): SecureCustomProperties =
WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED Property(S):
MsiLogFileLocation =
D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Wix\MyMetroApp\MyWixProject\bin\Debug\log.txt
Property(S): PackageCode = {569C58F8-77D1-4804-A8E3-699F32A371B0}
Property(S): ProductState = 5 Property(S): RestrictedUserControl = 1
Property(S): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\mina.samy Property(S):
CLIENTUILEVEL = 0 Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 8608 Property(S):
PRODUCTLANGUAGE = 1033 Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL Property(S):
EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1 Property(S):
SECONDSEQUENCE = 1 Property(S): REMOVE = ALL Property(S):
MsiSystemRebootPending = 1 Property(S): VersionDatabase = 405
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00 Property(S): VersionNT = 603
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 603 Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0 Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor =
0 Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1 Property(S): WindowsFolder =
C:\Windows\ Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\ Property(S):
System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\ Property(S): SystemFolder =
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1 Property(S):
TempFolder = C:\Users\MINA~1.SAM\AppData\Local\Temp\ Property(S):
CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ Property(S):
ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\ Property(S):
CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\ Property(S):
AppDataFolder = C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Roaming\ Property(S):
FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\mina.samy\Favorites\ Property(S):
NetHoodFolder =
C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network
Shortcuts\ Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\mina.samy\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder =
C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer
Shortcuts\ Property(S): RecentFolder =
C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder =
C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder =
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\ Property(S):
CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\ Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder
= C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Local\ Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\mina.samy\Pictures\ Property(S): AdminToolsFolder =
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative
Tools\ Property(S): StartupFolder =
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder =
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ Property(S):
StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ Property(S):
FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\ Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1 Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6 Property(S): Msix64 = 6 Property(S): Intel =
6 Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 3977 Property(S): VirtualMemory = 1633
Property(S): LogonUser = mina.samy Property(S): UserSID =
S-1-5-21-1777408072-1188702606-1563503735-30603 Property(S):
UserLanguageID = 1033 Property(S): ComputerName = MSAMY-8-8375
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033 Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768 Property(S): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(S): BorderTop = 1 Property(S): BorderSide = 1 Property(S):
TextHeight = 16 Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3 Property(S):
ColorBits = 32 Property(S): TTCSupport = 1 Property(S): Time =
16:26:52 Property(S): Date = 2/24/2015 Property(S):
MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.33440 Property(S):
MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.9600.16384 Property(S):
RedirectedDllSupport = 2 Property(S): AdminUser = 1 Property(S):
MsiRunningElevated = 1 Property(S): Privileged = 1 Property(S):
USERNAME = is Property(S): DATABASE =
C:\Windows\Installer\1ac64ab4.msi Property(S): OriginalDatabase =
D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Wix\MyMetroApp\MyWixProject\bin\Debug\MyWixProject.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 5 Property(S): Preselected = 1 Property(S):
ROOTDRIVE = D:\ Property(S): CostingComplete = 1 Property(S):
OutOfDiskSpace = 0 Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 Property(S):
PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0 Property(S):
PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0 Property(S):
PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0 MSI (s) (D8:94) [16:26:52:102]:
MainEngineThread is returning 1603 MSI (s) (D8:B0) [16:26:52:106]:
RESTART MANAGER: Session closed. MSI (s) (D8:B0) [16:26:52:106]: No
System Restore sequence number for this installation. MSI (s) (D8:B0)
[16:26:52:109]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0 MSI (s)
(D8:B0) [16:26:52:109]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (D8:B0) [16:26:52:109]: Incrementing counter to disable
shutdown. Counter after increment: 0 MSI (s) (D8:B0) [16:26:52:109]:
Note: 1: 1402 2:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts
3: 2  MSI (s) (D8:B0) [16:26:52:110]: Note: 1: 1402 2:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts
3: 2  MSI (s) (D8:B0) [16:26:52:111]: Decrementing counter to disable
shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after
decrement: -1 MSI (s) (D8:B0) [16:26:52:111]: Destroying RemoteAPI
object. MSI (s) (D8:40) [16:26:52:111]: Custom Action Manager thread
ending. MSI (c) (A0:3C) [16:26:52:113]: Back from server. Return
value: 1603 MSI (c) (A0:3C) [16:26:52:113]: Decrementing counter to
disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter
after decrement: -1 MSI (c) (A0:3C) [16:26:52:113]: PROPERTY CHANGE:
Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'. Action
ended 16:26:52: ExecuteAction. Return value 3. MSI (c) (A0:3C)
[16:26:52:113]: Doing action: FatalError MSI (c) (A0:3C)
[16:26:52:113]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText  Action 16:26:52:
FatalError.  Action start 16:26:52: FatalError. Action 16:26:52:
FatalError. Dialog created Action ended 16:26:54: FatalError. Return
value 2. Action ended 16:26:54: INSTALL. Return value 3. Property(C):
UpgradeCode = {E37719C6-EE47-415C-9789-F36457739F83} Property(C):
POWERSHELLEXE =
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Property(C):
dirACF43D92150056BB5AF1BB3AF4AA9367 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\ Property(C):
dir85CD6D2E073C1AF7CCDD7F08B2828B13 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\
Property(C): dir27E2307338ED99741CE34470D7788F0A = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\cs-CZ\
Property(C): dir1737C711EC8ED7C44C1E30F357D02AC9 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\de-DE\
Property(C): dirB7BDE730B1FC6C8BAAEE9AE582B59FE7 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\en-US\
Property(C): dirDBCF52942BF84D8199FD0C3E2DE9ABA9 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\es-ES\
Property(C): dir74E6C4D40426FE7774C8697FFE6F97E4 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\fr-FR\
Property(C): dirEFF012DC0AAE03E3EAAA4821310C9DA4 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\it-IT\
Property(C): dir3C1D2B6785564FAB46D3040FC9CE4264 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\ja-JP\
Property(C): dir6A4E8B36315C88E1798B918ACF2988FD = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\ko-KR\
Property(C): dir3AD1E29BAEB95A64A569093166405201 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\pl-PL\
Property(C): dir9E520796F0CE303B4506F5EF7767C416 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\pt-BR\
Property(C): dirC238DC7D4277CB05BF94AF487B5D5D1E = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\ru-RU\
Property(C): dir53726EBC16CC1C77755E74D187F9A1AE = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\tr-TR\
Property(C): dirF3AB69CAA487FCD07F63CA17BEA4EB9E = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\zh-CN\
Property(C): dir9D7E2D39FDCE546D1355C94BD1276EF9 = C:\Program Files
(x86)\MyWixProject\MyMetroApp_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.resources\zh-TW\
Property(C): INSTALLFOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\MyWixProject\
Property(C): WixUIRMOption = UseRM Property(C): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(C): ARPNOMODIFY = 1 Property(C): ProgramFilesFolder =
C:\Program Files (x86)\ Property(C): TARGETDIR = D:\ Property(C):
Installed = 00:00:00 Property(C): Manufacturer = Mina Samy
Property(C): ProductCode = {C23520BB-5E8C-4B0A-AC6A-E3795798123F}
Property(C): ProductLanguage = 1033 Property(C): ProductName =
MyWixProject Property(C): ProductVersion = 1.0.0.0 Property(C):
DefaultUIFont = WixUI_Font_Normal Property(C): WixUI_Mode = Minimal
Property(C): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg Property(C):
SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(C): MsiLogFileLocation =
D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Wix\MyMetroApp\MyWixProject\bin\Debug\log.txt
Property(C): PackageCode = {569C58F8-77D1-4804-A8E3-699F32A371B0}
Property(C): ProductState = 5 Property(C): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
Property(C): RestrictedUserControl = 1 Property(C): CURRENTDIRECTORY =
C:\Users\mina.samy Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0 Property(C):
CLIENTPROCESSID = 8608 Property(C): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
Property(C): PRODUCTLANGUAGE = 1033 Property(C): VersionDatabase = 405
Property(C): VersionMsi = 5.00 Property(C): VersionNT = 603
Property(C): VersionNT64 = 603 Property(C): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 0 Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor =
0 Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 1 Property(C): WindowsFolder =
C:\Windows\ Property(C): WindowsVolume = C:\ Property(C):
System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\ Property(C): SystemFolder =
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ Property(C): RemoteAdminTS = 1 Property(C):
TempFolder = C:\Users\MINA~1.SAM\AppData\Local\Temp\ Property(C):
CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ Property(C):
ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\ Property(C):
CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\ Property(C):
AppDataFolder = C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Roaming\ Property(C):
FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\mina.samy\Favorites\ Property(C):
NetHoodFolder =
C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network
Shortcuts\ Property(C): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\mina.samy\Documents\
Property(C): PrintHoodFolder =
C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer
Shortcuts\ Property(C): RecentFolder =
C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(C): SendToFolder =
C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(C): TemplateFolder =
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\ Property(C):
CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\ Property(C): LocalAppDataFolder
= C:\Users\mina.samy\AppData\Local\ Property(C): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\mina.samy\Pictures\ Property(C): AdminToolsFolder =
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative
Tools\ Property(C): StartupFolder =
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(C): ProgramMenuFolder =
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ Property(C):
StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(C): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ Property(C):
FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\ Property(C): GPTSupport = 1
Property(C): OLEAdvtSupport = 1 Property(C): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): MsiAMD64 = 6 Property(C): Msix64 = 6 Property(C): Intel =
6 Property(C): PhysicalMemory = 3977 Property(C): VirtualMemory = 1636
Property(C): LogonUser = mina.samy Property(C): UserSID =
S-1-5-21-1777408072-1188702606-1563503735-30603 Property(C):
UserLanguageID = 1033 Property(C): ComputerName = MSAMY-8-8375
Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 1033 Property(C): ScreenX = 1280
Property(C): ScreenY = 1024 Property(C): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(C): BorderTop = 1 Property(C): BorderSide = 1 Property(C):
TextHeight = 16 Property(C): TextInternalLeading = 3 Property(C):
ColorBits = 32 Property(C): TTCSupport = 1 Property(C): Time =
16:26:54 Property(C): Date = 2/24/2015 Property(C):
MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.33440 Property(C):
MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.9600.16384 Property(C):
RedirectedDllSupport = 2 Property(C): AdminUser = 1 Property(C):
MsiRunningElevated = 1 Property(C): Privileged = 1 Property(C):
USERNAME = is Property(C): DATABASE =
C:\Windows\Installer\1ac64ab4.msi Property(C): OriginalDatabase =
D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Wix\MyMetroApp\MyWixProject\bin\Debug\MyWixProject.msi
Property(C): VersionHandler = 5.00 Property(C): UILevel = 5
Property(C): ACTION = INSTALL Property(C): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): ROOTDRIVE = D:\ Property(C): CostingComplete = 1
Property(C): OutOfDiskSpace = 0 Property(C): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0 Property(C):
PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0 Property(C):
PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0 Property(C): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(C): WixUI_InstallMode = Remove
=== Logging stopped: 2/24/2015  16:26:54 === MSI (c) (A0:3C) [16:26:54:025]: Note: 1: 1729  MSI (c) (A0:3C) [16:26:54:025]: Note:
1: 2205 2:  3: Error  MSI (c) (A0:3C) [16:26:54:025]: Note: 1: 2228 2:
3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1729  MSI
(c) (A0:3C) [16:26:54:025]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error  MSI (c)
(A0:3C) [16:26:54:025]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message`
FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709  MSI (c) (A0:3C) [16:26:54:025]:
Product: MyWixProject -- Configuration failed.

MSI (c) (A0:3C) [16:26:54:026]: Windows Installer reconfigured the
product. Product Name: MyWixProject. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product
Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Mina Samy. Reconfiguration success or
error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (A0:3C) [16:26:54:027]: Grabbed execution mutex. MSI (c)
(A0:3C) [16:26:54:027]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if
any exist MSI (c) (A0:3C) [16:26:54:028]: MainEngineThread is
returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 2/24/2015  16:26:54 ===
```

Comment: Do you have wix project source?

Comment: Take a look at the [log file](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/get_a_log.html)

Comment: @Justin Thanks, would you please check the log file in the update of the question?

Comment: The error code you need to google is near the bottom of that error log "1603" [This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/08/01/446328.aspx) may help you out.

Comment: @Justin Unfortunately, I can't find the reason